# internationalization mongoDB and Play

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, scala, playframework

i'm working on a scala CRUD application with playframework, I want to do the internationalization.

I did the play side but now I'm searshing for a reliable solution for doing the internationalization on mongoDB side.

I found that I have to work like this :

```
language{
"fr": français,
"en": frensh
}
```

My first question there is any better way to do this?

If the user enter some data in French for example, how to detect that these information are un French, and if my form is in English I should display the information even if there are in French how i can manage this case?